# Creating charts from sql files

Tags: sql, charts

I have a sql file containing information about a potential clients website keywords. I have exported this file from an ipad SEO app and got a sql file. I would like be able to show the information as charts or tables but Ive never worked with this file format before. Are there any good programs that can do this or is this a "hardcore programer task"?

Thank you!

Few lines taken from the sql file

```
 SQLite format 3@  Ô    Ô-‚%
‡‡bgÅÅ_tabledomainsdomainsCREATE TABLE domains (domain_name varchar(100), id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sort integer, country varchar(2))Å--Ågtablekeywords_historykeywords_historyCREATE TABLE keywords_history (position integer, date_added varchar(10), id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, kid integer)^ÅatablekeywordskeywordsCREATE TABLE keywords (sort integer, domain_id integer, id INTÅÇ  tablekeywordskeywordsCREATE TABLE keywords (sort integer, domain_id integer, id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, keyword_text varchar(500), country varchar(2))
ÉÓ◊¬∞ñÉliving.seSE-unifiedsweden.seSEes√§k.seSE#virotell.seSE)  mediaanalys.seSEapple.comUS˚˚≤£ìiT6 Ï› ¥ûÑo]D%÷¡•ëvW1·ƒ®˛ãtV)1hallm√∂bler malm√∂SE(#hallm√∂blerSE'/f√•t√∂ljer malm√∂SE%-belysning malm√∂SE#/
inredningskonsultSE"3heminredning malm√∂SE!%
heminredningSE$belysningSE$Atr√§dg√•rds m√∂bler malm√∂SE3
tr√§dg√•rds m√∂blerSE+  soffbord malm√∂SEsoffbordSE-k√∂ksbord malm√∂SEk√∂ksbordSE$Avardagsrums m√∂bler malm√∂SE&!f√•t√∂ljerSEsoffaSE3vardagsrums m√∂blerSE  )m√∂bler malm√∂SEm√∂blerSE  visitkortSE)webbutvecklingSE!webbdesignSE!web designSEadwordsSE
ppcSE
/sponsrade l√§nkarSE
seoSE   3s√∂kmarknadsf√∂ringSE
3s√∂kmotoroptimeringSE  !v√§rmepumpSE!abonnemangSEvirotellSE    mobilSE
teleSE
ppcSE   3s√∂kmotoroptimeringSEseoSE apple )˚˚∏•íÄn\J9&Ì⁄»∂§íÄn\J8&Ó€…∑•ìÅo]K9'ÒﬁÀ∏¶îÇp2!2013-02-07
1!2013-02-070!2013-02-07/!2013-02-07
.!  2013-01-24-!2013-01-24,!)2013-01-24+!2013-01-24
*!2013-01-24)!2013-01-24(!2013-01-24
'!2013-01-23&!2013-01-23%!2013-01-23
$!2013-01-23#!2013-01-23"!2013-01-23
!!2013-01-11
 !2013-01-11!2013-01-11!    2013-01-11!2013-01-11!)2013-01-11!2012-12-24!2012-12-24!2012-12-24!2012-12-24!2012-12-24!2012-12-24!2012-12-24
!2012-12-24!2012-12-24!2012-12-24
!2012-12-19 !   2012-12-19!2012-12-19!%2012-12-19
!2012-12-16!'2012-12-16 !   2012-12-16
!2012-12-16     !2012-12-16!2012-12-16!2012-12-16!2012-12-16!2012-12-14!)2012-12-14 !   2012-12-14! 2009-06-05! @2009-2
2pÓ‹À∏•íÄn\J9&Ì⁄»∂§íÄn\J8&Ó€…∑•ìÅo]K9'ÒﬁÀ∏¶îÇp2!2013-02-07
1!2013-02-070!2013-02-07/!2013-02-07
.!  2013-01-24-!2013-01-24,!)2013-01-24+!2013-01-24
*!2013-01-24)!2013-01-24(!2013-01-24
'!2013-01-23&!2013-01-23%!2013-01-23
$!2013-01-23#!2013-01-23"!2013-01-23
!!2013-01-11
 !2013-01-11!2013-01-11!    2013-01-11!2013-01-11!)2013-01-11!2012-12-24!2012-12-24!2012-12-24!2012-12-24!2012-12-24!2012-12-24!2012-12-24
!2012-12-24!2012-12-24!2012-12-24
!2012-12-19 !   2012-12-19!2012-12-19!%2012-12-19
!2012-12-16!'2012-12-16 !   2012-12-16
!2012-12-16     !2012-12-16!2012-12-16!2012-12-16!2012-12-16!2012-12-14!)2012-12-14 !   2012-12-14! 2009-06-05! @2009-06-01
!¶Ó‹ ∏¶îÇo]K'›À∏î¶Å9o]J8%Ó‹ ∏¶U!2013-02-180T!2013-02-18/S!2013-02-18.R!2013-02-18-Q!2013-02-18,P!2013-02-18+O!2013-02-18*N!
2013-02-18)M!2013-02-18(L!2013-02-18'K!2013-02-18&J!2013-02-18%H!2013-02-18#F!2013-02-18!G!2013-02-18"D!+2013-02-18C!2013-02-18B!2013-02-18A!2013-02-18@!2013-02-18?!2013-02-18>!2013-02-18I!2013-02-18$<!2013-02-18;!2013-02-18:!
2013-02-189!2013-02-188!2013-02-077!2013-02-076!2013-02-075!2013-02-074!2013-02-073!2013-02-07
'VÌﬂ¡≤£ìiT6 Ï› ¥ûÑo]D&÷¡•ëvW1·ƒ®˛ãtV)1hallm√∂bler malm√∂SE(#hallm√∂blerSE'/f√•t√∂ljer malm√∂SE%-belysning malm√∂SE#/
inredningskonsultSE"3heminredning malm√∂SE!%
heminredningSE$belysningSE$Atr√§dg√•rds m√∂bler malm√∂SE3
tr√§dg√•rds m√∂blerSE+  soffbord malm√∂SEsoffbordSE-k√∂ksbord malm√∂SEk√∂ksbordSE$Avardagsrums m√∂bler malm√∂SE&!f√•t√∂ljerSEsoffaSE1vardagsrumsm√∂blerSE   )m√∂bler malm√∂SEm√∂blerSE  visitkortSE)webbutvecklingSE!webbdesignSE!web designSEadwordsSE
ppcSE
/sponsrade l√§nkarSE
seoSE   3s√∂kmarknadsf√∂ringSE
3s√∂kmotoroptimeringSE  !v√§rmepumpSE!abonnemangSEvirotellSE    mobilSE
teleSE
ppcSE   3s√∂kmotoroptimeringSEseoSE apple macUS
[Ì”¡®ñ|[07sovrumsm√∂bler malm√∂SE/)sovrumsm√∂blerSE.sovrumSE-'mattor malm√∂SE,mattorSE+)matbord malm√∂SE*matbordSE
```

Comment: a sql file typically contains a series of database commands, which could be many different things. Could you edit your post to include what the first few lines of the sql looks like (you should be able to open it in any text editor)

Comment: @JonnyCundall added a few lines Jonny

Comment: @Abel: It looks like that is a series of database commands, and does not include any data. How do you expect to show data as charts or tables, if you don't actually have the data?

Comment: @MarkBannister I added the whole code Mark, please look again, I really have no clue on whats what

Comment: @Abel: I'm not familiar with this format so I could be wrong, but it doesn't look like it contains website keyword data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file seems to be a SQLLite file which represents a database. To be able to use it, you need to install a SQLLite database browser like [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/). I think you may have to change the file extension to .db to be able to open it. If this works, I think your best bet would be to view the table data, and copy and paste it into excel or some similar program you are familiar with to create the chart.

Answer (score 2):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is a useful Java library for chart generation. While I've never used it with a sql file, I believe that it is possible.

Comment: Thank you Matt, I will check it out